# How to add sum of any column value to last column of last record in a tab delimited file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I need to take sum of col2 and add the value to last column of last record. Please advice, how can we achive this using UNIX shell script.

```
E.g Input file:
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
abc 2   A   null
bcd 3   B   null
adf 4   C   null

Output file
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
abc 2   A   null
bcd 3   B   null
adf 4   C   9
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to preserve white space in your output:

```
$ awk '{sum+=$2; s=s $0 ORS} END{ sub("null"ORS"$",sum,s); print s}' file
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
abc 2   A   null
bcd 3   B   null
adf 4   C   9
```

or:

```
$ awk '{sum+=$2; printf "%s",p} {p=$0 ORS} END{ sub("null$",sum); print}' file
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
abc 2   A   null
bcd 3   B   null
adf 4   C   9
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk script will do it I think:

```
awk '{sum+=$2; if (NR != 4) print; } END {$4=sum; print;}' infile
```

**EDIT:** Or even better:

```
awk '{sum+=$2; if (NR>1) print x; x=$0} END {$4=sum; print $0;}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -v last="$(wc -l < file.txt)" 'NR == 1 { print; next } { sum += $2 } NR == last { sub($NF, sum) }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
abc 2   A   null
bcd 3   B   null
adf 4   C   9
```

Comment: @user1789649: Don't forget to accept an answer if it has helped you. This will essentially close the question. You can accept an answer by clicking the tick to the left of your favorite answer. Cheers.